# why my rating bar is not working properly

Tags: android

I have rating bar in my activity, I would like to give rating, if I click on 2nd star 3rd star is also selected why it is selecting I can't find out the reason can anyone help me please. Here is my xml code

```
<RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:stepSize="1"
                        android:theme="@style/rating3"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
                        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
                        />
```

I am getting the value of rating using this java code

```
final String rating = String.valueOf(ratingbar1.getRating());
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: I wanted to give rating 2 so I am clicking on 2nd star but 3rd star is also selected though I did not click on it

Comment: If you carefully notice... if you are touching 2nd star on the end side, means after 50% then it will select 3rd start.. if you touch 2nd star on the starting , it will select the same.

Comment: how to avoid it

Comment: Use Math.ceil or Math.floor method (as per your need) in ratingbar1.getRating. then get the value

Comment: @Swapna  - i check your code -remove android:theme="@style/rating3" and check it

Comment: https://github.com/ome450901/SimpleRatingBar    refer this link

Answer (score 0):

I am using this Rating Bar and working fine .You can check it.

In xml use this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingstar"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:rating="1"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            />
```

And for getting how much star is selected 
Use

```
ratingstar.getRating().
```

Hope.it will helps you.